# Php auto go to the next page and scrape

Tags: php

I'm new to Php and Im trynna code a tool that scrape Amazon product title 
Right now, I can scrape the first page but I need the tool to go to the next page until there is no page left and do the same task like the 1st page which is scraping.
Here is the code:

```
    <?php
$file_string = file_get_contents('http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_3737671_pg_1?rh=n%3A1055398%2Cn%3A%211063498%2Cn%3A3206324011%2Cn%3A3737671&page=1&ie=UTF8&qid=1361609819');
preg_match_all('/<span class="lrg bold">(.*)<\/span>/i', $file_string, $links);
for($i = 0; $i < count($links[1]); $i++) {
echo $links[1][$i] . '<br>';
}

?>
```

Any help is appreciate...

Comment: Use apis If provided to handle data..not sure what exactly you want to achieve from this ...however in the current case you can just iterate for page ie page=2,page=3....and so on..but you have to improve it further as I am sure it will exhaust memory much

Comment: i think @swapnesh is correct its not the correct way of doing it use something like Amazon Product API (https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get all pages HTML as one var this would do the trick

```
    <?php

    $html = '';

    $file_string = file_get_contents('http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_3737671_pg_1?rh=n%3A1055398%2Cn%3A%211063498%2Cn%3A3206324011%2Cn%3A3737671&page=1&ie=UTF8&qid=1361609819');
    preg_match_all('/<span class="lrg bold">(.*)<\/span>/i', $file_string, $links);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($links[1]); $i++) {
        $html .= file_get_contents($links[1][$i]);
    }

    echo "all pages combined:\n".$html;

    ?>
```

However, more than likely your server will time out, run out of memory or something else will go wrong. To scrape HTML content you'd be better off creating a URL list first, then scraping it one at a time. You could do this via a HTML page that calls the scraper via AJAX.